# Python: Using the same function as both a generator and a regular function

Tags: python, generator, subroutine

Is it possible to use a function as both a regular function (that does stuff and returns) and a generator function?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.make_generator = False

    def foo(self):
        gen = (x for x in my_list)
        for x in gen:
            # Do some stuff
                if self.make_generator:
                    yield
        # This return will raise a StopIteration
        return
```

The idea here was that if self.make_generator is False, then I don't want foo to yield; I want it to not be a generator so that I can call it like:

```
    foo()
```

And if I wanted it to yield between iterations, I'd make it a generator like so:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.make_generator = True
        self.foo_gen = self.foo()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.foo_gen.next()
```

But it seems that this is not possible. I want to keep my code dry but am not sure how I can control when foo is a generator and when it executes like a regular function.

Thanks!

Comment: a function cannot both yield and return ... you should be able to make your code plenty dry without that feature